# dynamically changing name of an array in c++

Tags: c++

Hi I have a problem where at compile time, I don't know how many vectors in my program are needed. The number required depends on a data set given at run-time, which will results in the range of vectors needed to be from 1 to N.

So if the data set requires ten vectors, it will create vec1,vec2,......vecN

How can i dynamically create the vectors so that they all have a different name?

I would then need to call each array separately. Presumably 
I could just use strings and a few loops for this.

Comment: or you can use vector of vectors vector<vector<xxx>> v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that directly. However, you could use a map to store a vector name, and the vector itself:

```
map<string, vector<int> > myMap;
```

You can add elements simply like this (if the element with such key doesn't exist yet):

```
vector<int> vec;
myMap["vec"] = vec;
```

If you'll do it with a key that already exists, the value will be replaced. For example:

```
vector<int> vec;
vector<int> vec1;
myMap["vec"] = vec;
myMap["vec"] = vec1;//now myMap["vec"] holds the vec1 vector
```

You can also easlly access elements like this:

```
myMap["vec"]//this will access the vector with the key "vec1"
```

Comment: I recommend using `unordered_map` to waste less resources.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I know this is not the appropriate place but I have no other way to contact you. You can't plagiarize 30+ tag wikis and expect to reap a bunch of rep for it. They're all soon to be rejected. I'll delete this comment shortly.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a vector to contain your vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> my_vector_of_vectors;

// Add a vector
my_vector_of_vectors.push_back(std::vector<int>{});

// Add a number to the inner vector
my_vector_of_vectors[0].push_back(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a vector of vectors, vec[0] to vec[n], each one containing the vector.

However, this works est if you know the number of vectors (eg 10). If you need to add new ones on-demand, then a list of vectors or a map might be a better option for you.